# Getting blank screen when trying to use ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am trying to use ng-repeat for a 'blog' sort of thing, and I'm just getting a blank screen with no errors in console, I've been playing with it but can't figure out what I've done wrong! Can anyone help? Here's my code:

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="blog.js"></script>
<div class="myBlog" ng-app="app" ng-controller="blogController" ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index">
<h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
<p>{{post.date}}</p>
<p>{{post.content}}</p>
</div>
```

blog.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('blogController', function($scope) {

    $scope.posts = [
    {title:'Test Post',date:'5/10/16',content:'This is a test!'},
    {title:'Test Post 2',date:'5/10/16',content:'This is the second test!'}
    ];


});
```

and if this helps, when I inspect element in chrome on the open page, I see:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: post in posts track by $index -->
```

but still nothing displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the app and the controller call outside of the div specifying the ng-repeat.

```
<div class="myBlog" ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index">
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{post.date}}</p>
  <p>{{post.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Take a look at the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gb4DgQFkvAsub4FLebbG?p=preview

Typically, I like to make the `ng-app` call in the `html` tag. I also make the `ng-controller` call on a div element that wraps around all the code relative to that controller.

Comment: Great! But this is a angular template so no <HTML> and such, can I just wrap my current HTML in another div with the ng app and ng controller tags?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you dude!